# How to access custom twig extension in error pages

Tags: twig, symfony4

i overrided the twig error pages and i've got an extension to get some settings for layout but i can't access this extension in the error pages

Here is my extension

```php
/**
 * Class ThemeExtension.
 */
class ThemeExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    use SettingManagerTrait;

    /**
     * @var TokenStorageInterface
     */
    private $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * @var AuthorizationCheckerInterface
     */
    private $authorizationChecker;

    /**
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    private $stack;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $available_colors;

    /**
     * ThemeExtension constructor.
     *
     * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
     * @param AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker
     * @param RequestStack $stack
     * @param array $available_colors
     */
    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker, RequestStack $stack, array $available_colors)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->stack = $stack;
        $this->available_colors = $available_colors;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('theme_name', [$this, 'getThemeName']),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws NonUniqueResultException
     */
    public function getThemeName(): string
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to use this in error pages if somebody knows. Thank you for any help or idea. Maybe it's not possible